# Any Idea What This Bump Is?

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition

We discovered this bump behind our dog's shoulder.  It's maybe 3 - 4 mm (<sup>1</sup>/<sub>4</sub> inch) or so.  It feels more hard than squishy.  It doesn't seem to be an infection and it doesn't bother the dog when we touch it.  I'm wondering if anyone has a clue what it might be and whether it's something we should worry about or not.

Thanks in advance.

[image: bump behind dog's shoulder]

Comment: Whereabouts behind the shoulder please, underside or side or topside? It appears to be a nipple.

Comment: Looking at it I, myself, probably wouldn't worry about it, but I do make a point to note all new bumps and lumps and point them out to the vet at every visit.

Comment: yeah, i though it looked a bit like a nipple, too, but it's on the topside of the dog - maybe 2-3 inches from the center of his back.

Comment: This a question you should bring to your vet.  You dog has light skin and [per this answer it could be a cancer](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/575/does-a-dogs-pink-or-white-skin-need-special-care/583#583)

Comment: It could also just be a cyst.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a vet.  My labs have had bumps like that.  I trim around it with hair clipper and clean the area with alcohol.  It dries up and goes away.  If it does not get better in a couple days then see a vet.

You probably should not squeeze it.